# How do i change the pixel size when using SetPixel on a bitmap?

Tags: c#, winforms

```
newbitmap.SetPixel((int)clouds1[x].X, (int)clouds1[x].Y, Color.Red);
```

I set pixels in to a new bitmap with color red.
In form1 i show the newbitmap in pictureBox3:

```
pictureBox3.Image = CloudEnteringAlert.newbitmap;
```

But the pixels are very small almost cant be see on the pictureBox3.
How can i make the pixels bigger ?

Comment: You could draw rectangles. `Rectangle myRectangle = new Rectangle(100, 50, 80, 40); myGraphics.DrawRectangle(myPen, myRectangle);`... or make the bitmap smaller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't, but you can draw a circle instead.

```
using(var g = Graphics.FromImage(newbitmap)) {
    g.FillEllipse(Brushes.Red, (int)clouds1[x].X - radius, 
                               (int)clouds1[x].Y - radius, 2 * radius, 2 * radius);
}
```

I created an extension method that simplifies drawing a circle (here with float coordinates):

```
public static void FillCircle(this Graphics g, Brush brush,
                              PointF center, float radius)
{
    g.FillEllipse(brush, center.X - radius, center.Y - radius,
                         radius + radius, radius + radius);
}
```

If your clouds are `PoinF`'s you can call it like this:

```
using(var g = Graphics.FromImage(newbitmap)) {
    g.FillCircle(Brushes.Red, clouds1[x], radius);
}
```

If not, adapt the extension method accordingly. Place such extension methods in a static class.

In order to get smooth circles you can use antialiasing. Set the `SmoothingMode` of the `Graphics` object to the desired value before drawing circles:

```
g.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
```

Comment: This answer appears to assume `newbitmap` is a `Graphics` object.. not a `Bitmap` (as it appears in the question).

Comment: Yes, my mistake. You have to create a `Graphics` context from the bitmap. Corrected the examples.